# Setting Conditional RootPage in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to set Rootpage in this manner
Its working, but when navigating it shows error saying "nav Controller was destroyed" or "inserted view was already destroyed."
Can anyone please help me in this?

```
this.storage.get('hasSeenTutorial')
      .then((hasSeenTutorial) =>
 {
        if (hasSeenTutorial) 
       {
          afAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => 
         {
            if(auth)
            {
              this.rootPage = 'TabsPage';
              toaster.setMessage('Has Seen Tutorial YES Auth');
              toaster.present();
            }
            else
            {
              this.rootPage = 'LoginPage';
              toaster.setMessage('Has Seen Tutorial NOT Auth');
              toaster.present();
            }
        });
      } 
    else
      {
          this.rootPage = 'TutorialPage';
          toaster.setMessage('Has NOT Seen Tutorial');
          toaster.present();
      }
});
```

Comment: are you getting error for _all the conditions_? or one of them? Also where is this code present?

Comment: @suraj shouldn't he pass actual imported variable instead of string eg: `TabsPage` instead of `'TabsPage'` ?

Comment: @Dhyey not if he is using ionic 3 with lazy loading.

Comment: @suraj thanks, i didn't know about it.

Comment: @Dhyey check out http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/

Comment: When you declare the `rootPage` property, are you assigning anything, or just declaring it and leaving it undefined (like `public rootPage: any;`)?

Comment: @suraj I have added it to app.component.ts, and ya got the errors for all the conditions.

Comment: @sebaferreras I am leaving it as public rootPage: any